# Vulnerability Reporting from "random" dude

Tags: wordpress, cors

A few days ago I got an email to our dpo email address from a person I don't know who claims to be a Security Researcher. The email is well written and contains a POC with screenshots of a CORS Exploit (SOP Bypassed). My first reaction is "fishing for jobs". But when looking at the POC it seems he's just making an API call to the WP generated API and nothing more. I don't see how this is an actual vulnerability.

Here's the POC code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <center>
<h2>CORS POC Exploit</h2>
<div id="demo">
 <button type="button" onclick="cors()">Exploit</button>
</div> <script> function cors() { var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{ if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alert(this.responseText); } }; xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/wp-json/", true); xhttp.withCredentials = true; xhttp.send(); }
 </script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Did he just run his scanner and auto-generate emails not realizing he was scanning the standard Wordpress `wp-json` end point?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about "random dudes claiming to be security researchers".  This is normal and not a problem.  If he's including a PoC and not demanding money, then you have someone who is already fairly reasonable.  Evaluate their PoC.  Thank them for their time.  If applicable fix it according to your own priorities.  If you're not sure if it is applicable then explain your confusion and ask them for more details.  "Sending emails based on automated scanners" is not how it usually goes, but misunderstandings and reports that don't make sense certainly does happen

Comment: Thanks @ConorMancone that seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: The request seems to be crafted as a XSRF. So, by phishing a victime he could lead him to a webpage with this code. Then a request will be made to your website with the creds of the victim

Comment: This may help: https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/a-security-researcher-has-made-contact-what-do-i-do/

I've been on both sides of this, including eventually publishing details of severe vulnerabilities because the business decided to completely ignore me.  If you want to you can always drop by the [DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) and ask questions in a more "free form" style.

Comment: I took a quick peek and the endpoint in question is indeed configured to effectively disable CORS.  Whether that is a problem or not is another question entirely - if this endpoint doesn't take action, or is meant to be public, then the lack of CORS may be intentional.  It is a bit unusual though, so it's not crazy for a researcher to think it is a vulnerability.  If this is a wordpress standard feature then you would have to check wordpress docs.  Deciding whether or not this is a problem may be tricky.

Comment: But am I right assuming you could only exploit this in combination with social engineering? Additionally, we were also missing some security relevant HTTP headers which were now added.